# Can't enter recovery mode on Samsung Galaxy A10s after bootloader unlock

Tags: samsung, recovery-mode, twrp

So I unlocked my Samsung Galaxy A10s bootloader and wanted to flash TWRP. After flashing it, I realized I can't enter recovery mode. If I keep pressing the power + vol up, it just shows the bootloader unlock warning and keeps bootlooping. When I let go, it boots normally.

At first, I thought it was a TWRP problem. But then after it booted, I tried to enter recovery and it didn't enter (I tried via adb as well). After that, I again flashed the stock ROM using Odin; the same result,

Is there something I am doing wrong?